# Ionic 4: How to save images on device for offline mode that comes from firebase storage

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic4

I use **SQLite native plugin** for storing the text content but I need to do that with images too! ( For **OFFLINE** mode )

Converting the images to base64 string didn't work out with angular/ionic 4 so my question is:

## How to download the images with Native file transfer plugin provided by ionic/Cordova from images urls that comes from Firebase

I have read the docs but it is to basic and don't give much!

**the code the DOCS provide:** ( *I don't understand `file.pdf` on download method! the images can come with any extension like jpg/png ..etc* )

```
download() {
  const url = 'http://www.example.com/file.pdf';
  fileTransfer.download(url, this.file.dataDirectory + 'file.pdf').then((entry) => {
    console.log('download complete: ' + entry.toURL());
  }, (error) => {
    // handle error
  });
}
```

Comment: put snapshot of ionic info

Comment: what is version of webview plugin ?

Comment: webview version 3.2.1 I found a solution says install 1.2.1 but when I tried this crashed my app so I back to my latest one

Comment: have you tried normalizeURL(). because it work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for responding but I have figured out!

I have stored my Images on the phone then converted into a base64 image by using Cordova plugin for that which you can find [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/base64) then I added the base64 image to my storage with the text content.

Comment: HI I want to do the exact same thing can you guide me a lil bit..

Comment: Just use this plugin to convert any image you have to `base 64` format https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/base64 then just save the output using SQLite in your device storage, and when you go offline get pull the base64 images with your offline data you have saved

Answer (score 1):

`file.pdf` on download method is not a problem because you can get whole document/image name with extension from API response.

For example

```
for (let i = 0; i < res.data.length; i++) { 
     let fileName = res.data[i].name;
     let url = 'http://www.example.com/' + res.data[i].name;
     const _fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this._fileTransfer.create();
     _fileTransfer.download(url, this._file.dataDirectory + fileName).then((entry) => {
         console.log('download complete: ' + entry.toURL());
     }, (error) => {
         console.log(error);
     });
}
```

Then you can show images using **normalizeURL** that given a string representing a URL, [returns the URL path after stripping the trailing slashes](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/3.3.0/api/util/normalizeURL/).

```
import { normalizeURL } from 'ionic-angular';

{'filePath': normalizeURL(result[i].fileName)

<img src="{{filePath}}">
```

Comment: Yes that what I have done except the `normalizeUrl` has been deprecated with `ionic 4` so I didn't find a way to access the file without a `not allowed error` so I had to convert the image I have downloaded to base64 version and it worked but not happy with performance for that approach

Comment: @heshamshawky Did you try with `let win: any = window; 
let safeURL = win.Ionic.WebView.convertFileSrc('file:///myFile/....');` ?

Comment: I have tried it before your reply with seconds XD and it worked thanks a lot your answer is the best I got here

Answer (score 0):

You can use LocalStorage, more information here: https://ionicframework.com/docs/building/storage

An example that I used a few weeks ago to store Images.

```
 if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
      this.fileName = 'Image';
       this.filePath = this.file.documentsDirectory.replace(/file:\/\//g, '') + this.fileName;

    } else if (this.platform.is('android')) {
      this.fileName = 'Image';
        this.filePath = this.file.externalDataDirectory.replace(/file:\/\//g, '') + this.fileName;
```

Comment: I have downloaded the images successfully by file transfer plugin but when taking the URL from my phone and put it on the image src pops up an error says 
`Error: Not allowed to load local resource`
**So how to load images come from the phone now?**

Answer (score 0):

Firebase has cool [offline](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline) capabilities.
Try querying necessary data, and use it.

Otherwise use this [plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-transfer).

Comment: My question is how to use that plugin?! anyway I have used it and stored my image successfully but now I have a new error `Error: Not allowed to load local resource` comes when change the path for the image to phone path `file:////data/user/0/wysbird.ionic.starter/files/F1554080441-cover4.jpg` **so How I fix that?**